# Automatic install of eSim profile on iPhone - callback called too soon

Tags: ios, swift

We added eSim installation in our app and we have 2 flows: automatically install or manual installation of the profile.
I did all the configuration required as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605419/esim-integration-ios-how-to-use-restricted-api-addplan-to-enable-e-sim-profi). Manual installation works fine, but we have a problem with the automatically installation of the profile.

The code looks like this:

```
let planProvisioning = CTCellularPlanProvisioning()
let cellularPlanRequest = CTCellularPlanProvisioningRequest()
cellularPlanRequest.address = eSimResult.address
cellularPlanRequest.matchingID = eSimResult.code

planProvisioning.addPlan(with: cellularPlanRequest) { result in
    // this get's called immediately and the result is always .unknown
    print("cellularPlanRequest result is unknown", result == .unknown)
}
```

The problem is that the callback is called immediately with the result .unknown right after we call `planProvisioning.addPlan(with:)` and the system view with starting the install is shown - not when the user finished the install flow (successfully or not).

Did anyone get this to work ok? What did we miss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I was able to fix by declaring and instantiating planProvisioning separately from the func where I add the plan.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
private let planProvisioning = CTCellularPlanProvisioning() //this fixed the issue for me

func createEsimProvisioning() {
    let cellularPlanRequest = CTCellularPlanProvisioningRequest()
    cellularPlanRequest.address = eSimResult.address
    cellularPlanRequest.matchingID = eSimResult.code
    
    planProvisioning.addPlan(with: cellularPlanRequest) { result in
        // this get's called immediately and the result is always .unknown
        print("cellularPlanRequest result is unknown", result == .unknown)
    }
  }
}
```