‘Add eSIM’ option in the eSIM QR code long press context menu | WKWebView vs SFSafariViewController
I’m trying to show a eSIM QR code via a WKWebView and get the ‘Add eSIM’ option when the user long press on the QR code.
But when I long press on my device it doesn’t show the ‘Add eSIM’ option in the context menu.
with WKWebView:

struct QRView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        if let urlRequest = URL(string: url.absoluteString) {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: urlRequest))
        }
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {}
}

Then I tried to show the QR code using SFSafariViewController. it worked fine when I used the SFSafariViewController.
with SFSafariViewController:

    struct QRView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let urlString: String
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    init(urlString: String, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }
        let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        safariViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        safariViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        return safariViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}

How can I do the same with the WKWebView?
Any help is appreciated.

I don't think you can, because WKWebView doesn't recognise it as an eSim QR code. Requiring the user to long-press on the QR code is an obscure operation anyway and has discoverability issues IMO. You would be better off having a simple "Add eSim" button in your app to trigger the installation.

@Paulw11 Yes that's true. but to just add a button and trigger the installatio, a specific entitlement is required from apple which is granted for MNOs only.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605419/esim-integration-ios-how-to-use-restricted-api-addplan-to-enable-e-sim-prof

There's a better way to do this From iOS 17.4 and up.
Apple Supports eSIM install with Universal Link. Format goes like
https://esimsetup.apple.com/esim_qrcode_provisioning?carddata=LPA:1$GSMA_SMDP_Address$activation_code

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-17_5-release-notes#New-Features

Universal Links should be all lower case. Only the GSMA activation
code (QR code), passed in as carddata, is customized for the carrier’s
SM-DP+ and eSIM profile. Use the iOS user agent in web requests to
determine when to offer Universal Links for eSIM, which are only be
enabled on iOS 17.4 and later. (92405493)


Does anyone know if this method requires obtaining an esim entitlement from Apple? I cannot find any explicit information on this.

@ИсфанДжамалутдинов Installing with universal link doesn't require any special permissions from Apple.
